# Redux Saga dynamic action types?

Tags: react-native, redux

I am developing an app. In the **Settings** screen, I'm having a list of `Switch` which will update the API. How can I work with dynamic action_types and handle this in **Reducer**.

**Scenerio I need**

1. Every Switch state has to trigger an `sampleAction`
2. For same `switch` taps, `takeLatest` latest call should be considered
3. I can taps multiple `switch` at the same time.

Eg:) If I tap 5 different buttons, 5 API calls should go, but if I toggles between the same Switch 5 times, only latest should be considered.

**Sample Action with dynamic type 'key'**

```
export const sampleAction = (key) => {
    return {
        type: SETTINGS.ACTION_CHANGE + key
    };
};
```

Any solutions???

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use payload for it!
example:

```
export const sampleAction = (key) => {
    return {
        type: SETTINGS.ACTION_CHANGE,
        payload:{key}
    };
};
```

Comment: Kindly check my updated question, 

Eg:) If I tap 5 different buttons, 5 API calls should go, but I toggles between the same Switch 5 times, only latest should be considered. 

How can i do this in Saga layer.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this way**

```
export const sampleAction = (key) => {
  return {
      type: SETTINGS.ACTION_CHANGE + key,
      payload: key
  };
};
```

**Your reducer**

```
export default (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (`${action.type}${action.payload}` ) {
    case `${SETTINGS.ACTION_CHANGE}${action.payload}`:
      return {your new state}
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think you are just over complicating yourself. I kind of have the same situation in my app's settings page where I have multiple settings that can be switched on or off.

What you want to do is kind of not actually possible. Take your example

```
export const sampleAction = (key) => {
    return {
        type: SETTINGS.ACTION_CHANGE + key
    };
};
```

How will your reducer look like? It can't be `case SETTINGS.ACTION_CHANGE + key` What key?

So, I only see two solutions for your use case. You can dispatch a single action with a payload, like someone already mentioned, but then your saga would look like

```
function* saga(action) {
    if (action.payload === 'SETTING_1') {
        // Do stuff for that setting.
    }
}

export function* sagas() {
    yield takeEvery(SETTING.ACTION_CHANGE, saga);
}
```

But now you have a problem, you can't do the combination with `takeEvery` and `takeLatest` as you would have liked, because no matter the setting the user swtiched on or off, it still the same action type and still the same saga that runs.

So, a solution to this would be something of the following:

```
function* saga(action) {
    if (action.payload === 'SETTING_1') {
        yield put({ type: SETTING_1 });
    }
}

function* settingOne(action) {
    // Do stuff for setting 1.
}

export function* sagas() {
    yield takeEvery(SETTING.ACTION_CHANGE, saga);
    yield takeLatest(SETTING_1, settingOne);
}
```

Now your kind of doing exactly what you desired, you use `takeEvery` for each switch click, but if the same switched was clicked multiple times, then the `takeLatest` comes into place.

So, what could possibly be wrong with this? Well, you actually don't have any dynamic keys anymore, the parameter is passed into the payload and checked in the main saga, than a different saga runs based on that.

Which means, what would be the best way in my opinion. Forget about the dynamic things (I know you want to have less actions, and so...) and keep it simple, like so:

```
function* settingOne(action) {
    // Do stuff for setting 1.
}

export function* sagas() {
    yield takeLatest(SETTING_1, settingOne);
 }
```

Basically, dispatch an unique action with an unique type for each setting and use `takeLatest` to handle the quick toggling on the same setting.

Hope this kind of clarifies why the dynamic action types won't work. At least that's what I know, maybe there is a way I haven't heard of :)

Comment: I created custom array for parsing it into SectionList with each object contains key, title etc. As per your opinion If I had 10 settings item, then I've to create 10 action. If in nearby future if I've to add another item, then I've to create new action for that. That's why am looking for dynamic approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran in to this problem and found an elegant solution as mentioned here: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/694#issuecomment-266702056 by the maintainer.

```
import { channel } from 'redux-saga';
import { put, select, take, takeLatest} from 'redux-saga/effects';

    function* watcherSaga() {
      const map = {};
      while (true) {
        const action = yield take(SETTINGS.ACTION_CHANGE);
        const { key } = action;
        if (!map[key]) {
          map[key] = channel();
          yield takeLatest(map[key], workerSaga);
        }
        yield put(map[key], action);
      }
    }
```

Comment: @ArunShankar see here